# Access JSON data without subscription key

Tags: c#, json

Is it possible to download the get the JSON Data without subscription key?

I can only view the JSON data via network developer tool.

But in c# I must need to input the subscription key in order to read the JSON. and this is the error without subscription key:

```
   {
  "statusCode": 401,
  "message": "Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API."
}
```

and here's my code with subscription key (which I can read the json):

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "b70a21a492a6402492ec40b3065c017d"); //hope that I can still read the json strings without this key
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0");

string url = "URL";

using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is an [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/api-management/) convention for requiring an API key. It is up to the API's publisher what authentication they require, if any, and without knowing what API you are using your question is unanswerable beyond that. You should ask the API's publisher what they expect.

For what it's worth, the method you are using looks fine for passing the subscription key in the standard format. You will have to ask the publisher why this is not being accepted.

Comment: Ah I see. sorry I'm just started learning regarding with API

I can actually get the subscription key if I only look on network developer and it's available there. I thought there's a way to pass the url without the key. 
Or do you suggest some way if there's any?

Comment: @zackmark15 try it. If the request is rejected; probably not. But as I said, to know for sure you'd have to consult the publisher or their documentation to know what they expect.